# Is there any difference in rewards for completing Solo versus Group Recon Training?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

On free days in the Monastery, I have the option to do Recon Training, which is a glorified game of hide and seek. I can either play one on one, four times, with each of the visiting exchange students, or I can opt for Group Recon, in which I have 90 seconds to find all four.

To date, I’ve only been able to successfully find 3 out of 4 on the group setting, and the rewards for doing so *appear* to be identical to competing three of the games of one on one.

Is there a bonus for finding all four in group mode, or are the rewards identical to finding each of the four individually?

Comment: I don't want to post as an answer as I'm not entirely sure this is correct, but from testing it appears the items are identical. However, I think you might get slightly more prestige from finding all four at once than from finding them individually. Once you have enough prestige, you will unlock a new battalion; from that point on, you can no longer gain prestige. So the only difference would be the chance to unlock the battalion earlier than otherwise. (And to save time).

Answer (score 0):

The difference in rewards is only for prestige as far as I know, the Essar Research group isn't unlocked quicker with group Recon. There is very few information available about this feature sadly.